# How to pass multiple parameters in Url.Action()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, parameters, actionresult

I want to pass multiple parameters from Url.Action, Here is code in view

```
 window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ABC", "XYZ", new { @A= ViewBag.A , @B =  ViewBag.B })";
```

And this is my Method in Controller **XYZ**

```
 public ActionResult ABC(string A, string B)
 {
    // Some Code
 }
```

I always get values in first parameter only and 2nd one is always null. Either if I but **B** first. 2nd one is always null.
VIEW is basically under JavaScript function.
Here is the URL: `http://localhost/CargoMainSite/XYZ/ABC?A=1&amp;B=2`
Please note there is some extra text between Parameter one and Parameter two, that is "amp;" if I explicitly removes it. It works fine and get proper values.

Comment: Thanks @Lalit Kumar for edit.

Comment: Why using post if you are exposing both parameters in url?

Comment: Lets leave it. What if it is not POST?

Comment: @ggui I just edited my question

Comment: i dont know your scenario, but actually i dont think its the best way to execute a action with parameters, i mean, using location.href property. Can you use an ajax get method instead?

Comment: @ggui Please specify how can I use it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reason why Url.Action not working is that the & char in url is encoded, so you must use **@Html.Raw** as below

```
 window.location.href = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ABC", "XYZ", new { @A= ViewBag.A , @B =  ViewBag.B }))";
```

Comment: Thanks @Abbas galiyakot it really worked perfectly.
But I have a question. Please let me know if there will be any problem using @Html.Raw() like cross scripting? spamming etc?

Comment: the risk is in how it is used

If you are displaying user entered information it is better to use @Html.Encode().

In another words, if you are displaying non-user eneterd data you are safe to go with @Html.Raw()

Comment: This worked for me --> window.location.href = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ABC", "XYZ", new { A= ViewBag.A , B =  ViewBag.B }))";